# pandas dataframe bar plot put space between bars

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, bar-chart, seaborn

So I want my image look like this
[image: Ideal Image]

But now my image look like this
[image: Image i have now]

How do I reduce the space between bars without making the bar width into 1?

Here is my code:

```
plot=repeat.loc['mean'].plot(kind='bar',rot=0,alpha=1,cmap='Reds',
       yerr=repeat.loc['std'],error_kw=dict(elinewitdh=0.02,ecolor='grey'),
       align='center',width=0.2,grid=None)

plt.ylabel('')
plt.grid(False)
plt.title(cell,ha='center')
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.ylim(0,120)
plt.tight_layout()`
```

Comment: Why don't you want to change the width of the bars?

Comment: I figured this problem out by using other ways. But do you know how to change the error bar so that it only shows the upper bound instead of both upper and lower bound? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

make the plot from scratch if the toplevel functions from pandas or seaborn do not give you the desired result! :)

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# some fake data
data = sp.randn(10,10) + 1
data = data[sp.argsort(sp.average(data,axis=1))[::-1],:]
avg = sp.average(data,axis=1)
std = sp.std(data,axis=1)

# a practical helper from seaborn to quickly generate the colors
colors = sns.color_palette('Reds',n_colors = data.shape[0])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pos = range(10)
ax.bar(pos,avg,width=1)
for col,patch in zip(colors,ax.patches):
    patch.set_facecolor(col)
    patch.set_edgecolor('k')

for i,p in enumerate(pos):
    ax.plot([p,p],[avg[i],avg[i]+std[i]],color='k',lw=2, zorder=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I solved the answer by using other people's solution. Your solution actually didnt really help me. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: ah I misunderstood you.

Comment: @nonickname consider adding your solution as an edit or response if you did find the solution.